# Guzzle request from virtual host has wrong ip

Tags: apache, curl, guzzle

I have a web server with differents IP addresses.
Apache virtualhosts and DNS are mapped like this :

```
ip1 => ip1.domain.com
ip2 => ip2.domain.com
ip3 => ip3.domain.com
```

I did this so i can use guzzlehttp from different IP addresses.

But if I do this, from any on those virthual host :

```
$client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client();
$url = "https://www.whatismyip.com";
$response = $client->request('GET', $url);
$content = $response->getBody();
```

I walways get the IP from the server, not from the virtualhost.

Am I missing something ? Is there a better way to do this ?

Thanks for your help,

Answer (score 0):

Turns out all it need is to specify the network interface in Guzzle.

No need for different virtual host, one is enough.

Example:

```
$client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client(['curl' => [ CURLOPT_INTERFACE => 'eth0:1' ]]);
```